# Average velocity of a ball thrown up in the air.

Tags: calculus

A ball is thrown straight up in the air with a velocity of $65 \,m/s$. After $t$ seconds the height is given as $y=65t-16t^2$. Give the average velocity for the time period beginning when $t=1$ and lasting

1. $0.5\,s$
2. $0.1\,s$
3. $0.01\,s$

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You know velocity is position divided by time, so you can just plug in t=1, t=1.5, t=1.1, and t=1.01 to find the position, then find the average velocity.

Comment: Add some air drag and this will be a quite interesting problem.

Comment: Thanks. Plugged in 0.5 for part a and got 28.5 so do I now divide that by 0.5?

Comment: Average velocity from time $a$ to time $b$ is $\frac{s(b)-s(a)}{b-a}$ where $s(t)$ is the position (height) at time $t$.

Comment: Sorry really understand what the s,a, and b, represent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$v_{av}=\frac{\text{total displacement}}{\text{total time taken}}$$
$$v_{av}=\frac{y(t_2)-y(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}$$
where $y(t)=65t-16t^2$